Check if a port is blocked with socat

How to check if a port is blocked with socat?
How to check with IPv6?

I heard a saying that machines behind NAT can still be directly connected via IPv6, is that true?
Anyway, say I have a machine behind very complicated setup, and I want to verify if a certain port can be reached, by either IPv4 or IPv6, how to do that with socat?
Basically I need to start socat on the machine to listen, then try to conect to it via socat from other machines. I've read https://copyconstruct.medium.com/socat-29453e9fc8a6, and found it a bit complicated, but I cannot just use netcat because my netcat version does not support IPv6, as per Netcat - How to listen on a TCP port using IPv6 address?.

Adding as a comment rather than an answer as it only addresses one of the questions you posed:  It is not true that machines behind NAT can still be directly connected to (from outside the NAT gateway), because any connection through NAT is by definition indirect.

That's a good one, :), as the rest do not need answers any more, at least for my situation. But anyone feel free anyway. BTW, suppose it's those machines behind IPS that don't have any IPv4 addresses from ISP, would they be accessible via IPv6 from outside of ISP, @DopeGhoti?
